# I am using lisp in a box environment

Tags: common-lisp

```
CL-USER> (load "hello-world.lisp")
#P"g:/Machinelearning/Beginner/lispbox-0.7/hello-world.lisp"
```

How do I know the file is compiled? What command should be used to display the content of the file? How to load files from other folders (read: other than default)?

Comment: There are three unrelated questions here. The second can be Googled trivially, and the third can be discovered by trying the most logical thing.

Comment: after loading the lisp file, check out any function that you got from it with [`compiled-function-p`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw70/CLHS/Body/f_cmpd_f.htm#compiled-function-p)

Comment: Do you mean [this Lispbox](https://github.com/andreer/lispbox) ? It seems outdated. What about Portacle or other solutions ? See https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/getting-started.html and https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/editor-support.html

Answer (score 1):

> How do I know the file is compiled?

By convention `.lisp` files are Lisp source code, and compiled files usually have `.fasl` extensions.

> What command should be used to display the content of the file?

Load it into a text editor, just like source code in any other language.

> How to load files from other folders (read: other than default)?

Use a pathname:

```
(load "/dir1/dir2/otherfile.lisp")
```